# get img src from an img loaded dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic-data, image

I am looking at getting the image name from an image with a src loaded dynamically.
Basically what I am doing is using the Google chat badge on a site to live chatting. And else where on the page, I have an image saying Live Chat:Online or Live Chat:Offline. And I want this to change depending on whether I am available to chat or not. Does this make sense?

Anyway, the easiest way I figure to do this would be check the img url. If the img is offline.gif then obviously I am offline.

An example of a dynamically loaded img would be something like

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/talk/service/badge/Show?encrypted_acount_id_here" />
```

Once this image has loaded, it loads one of the following images
"http://www.google.com/talk/service/resources/offlinef.gif"
"http://www.google.com/talk/service/resources/idlef.gif"
"http://www.google.com/talk/service/resources/onlinef.gif"

Hopefully this make sense now.

Thanks heaps

Comment: I don't think your approach is the right way to go. It's almost certainly not doable through JavaScript at least. I'd suggest looking for Google chat presence APIs; you should be able to make an AJAX callback to find out whether you are on- or offline.

Comment: Hmm I think my previous comment was no good. Although there is some kind of XMPP API, it looks overly complicated. Furthermore, it looks like there is some kind of badge thing that you can request that will return a different image tag. There is some PHP sample code on the internet... see e.g. http://www.digimantra.com/google/show-google-talk-status-website/. It would be kind of a pain to convert to jQuery/AJAX, but certainly doable.

Comment: The second options worked sweet. I see there is a disclaimer on that site saying that it's not foolproof, but from the limited testing I have done, it seems doable. And at the present time, it seems the only  or best way to go. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the image itself is generated dynamically in which case there wont be another source. The only reason you would see another source when you view it's properties is because of the content headers of the generated image.

If the src itself however is changed dynamically your best bet would to just get the src attribute from the element.

If by chance what you actually are looking for is a way to programatically find a way to know if you are offline or online, you could try to get the alt attribute from the image. Most websites have an alt description for the image element and it should hopefully read online if the online image is showing or offline if the offline image is showing.